# How to prove by induction the constructibility of a line segment of length $\sqrt{n}$?

Tags: geometry, induction, geometric-construction

How to prove the following statement by induction?

If a line of unit length is given, then a line of length $\sqrt{n}$ can be constructed with straightedge and compass for each positive integer $n$.

The statement obviously holds for $n=1$.

Now we assume that we can construct a line of length $\sqrt{k}$ with straightedge and compass, where $k$ is a given positive integer.

How to proceed from here?

That is, how to show from this that a line of length $\sqrt{k+1}$ can also be constructed with straightedge and compass?

Comment: See the [spiral of Theodorus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_of_Theodorus).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Pythagoras' theorem for the right-angled triangle with legs $\sqrt{k}$ and $1$.

Comment: ... and the right triangle can be achieved by this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7bkNNYN-j6E)